# Can't override Bulma variables using Vue Loader

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, node-sass, vue-loader

I'm starting a personal project using Vue CLI, installed Bulma as it can be customized easily with my own variable values. I tried to make a change to make Bulma variables available on my Vue components:

*vue.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: '@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works well for referencing Bulma variables in components, but now there are some initial values on the global styles I'm not able to change using custom variables. I can assign a value to them and I can reuse them on the same file but they don't change Bulma styles overall - this doesn't happen with all variables though, as I could change typography variables without problems.

*_variables.scss*

```
$purple: #8A4D76;
$middle-blue: #90ddf0;
$primary: $purple; // doesn't work
$link: $middle-blue; // doesn't work
$widescreen-enabled: false;
$fullhd-enabled: false;

$button-text-color: $grey-light; // this does work using $link or $primary

$family-primary: "Exo 2", sans-serif;
$family-secondary: "Metrophobic", sans-serif;
$family-code: "Parisienne", cursive;
```

*index.scss* - This file is imported in *App.vue*

```
@import "typography";
@import "variables";
@import "bulma";
@import "styles";
```

I tried importing the `_variables.scss` file into `vue.config.js` options and it works but doing that I lose access to Bulma predefined variables. I need to override some variables but I also want to use the ones Bulma already has defined as well.

What am I missing here? Why can't I override all Bulma variables?

Answer (score 0):

This should work in vue.config.js if your project is built via `vue-cli`

```js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `
          @import "@/scss/_variables.scss";
          @import "@/scss/_mixins.scss";
        `
      }
    }
  }
};
```

and assume you have `npm install --save-dev node-sass sass-loader`

Comment: By `_mixins.scss` do you mean the Bulma file?